# break the for loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, break

I have written a matlab code and want to terminate the code after finding the first one in the matrix. BUT, it continues until the last one and then break works. What is the problem?

```
% The code is as follows:
     for i=1:n
        for j=1:m
            if (bw(i,j)==1)  % element with value one  
                p1(1)=i;p1(2)=j;
                % fprintf('value of a: %d\n', i ,j)
                sprintf('Found first one in the loop!!')
                break;    % terminate 
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: The `break` exits the inner `for`, but not the outer. Anyway, this can probably be done without loops. Please describe what you want to achieve, with example input and output

Comment: Put this code in an appropriately named function, and `return` instead of `break`ing because, like @LuisMendo said, the `break` exits the inner `for`, not both of them.

Comment: You can also set `i = n` and `j = m` inside the `if` statement manually to ensure both loops terminate.  `break` only kills the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to **find the first `1` value in a matrix**, searching in **row-major order** (increase column index first, then row index). You can do that without loops using the [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function:

```
M = [0 1; 1 1]; %// example matrix
v = 1; %// value you want to find
[col, row] = find(M.'==v, 1);
```

Note that the matrix is transposed and the order of the two outputs of `find` is reversed. This is because Matlab finds elements in column-major order (increase row index first, then column index).

In the above example, with

```
M =
     0     1
     1     1
```

the result is

```
row =
     1
col =
     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `break` exits only the inner loop (the one that runs with `j`) but not the outer loop (the one that runs with `i`), you can tackle the problem by using a simple boolean which you initially set as `false`.
When you break the inner loop, change it to `true` and then check (in the outer loop) if such boolean is `true`. If it is, also break the outer loop.

```
IWantToBreak=false;
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        if (bw(i,j)==1)  % element with value one  
            p1(1)=i;p1(2)=j;
            % fprintf('value of a: %d\n', i ,j)
            sprintf('Found first one in the loop!!')
            IWantToBreak=true;
            break;    % terminate 
        end
    end
    if IWantToBreak==true
        break;
    end
end
```